# triggers don't update as expected in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've written some code that deals with triggers. the main idea is to create dynamic triggers to cells of a sheet and based on the value of the cell the counter add or subtract from the total selected. Let me present it with an example and the code to make it clearer:
This is how my excel sheets appear.

```
A B C D E
1 
2
3
```

to limit the scope, i have 4 columns and 3 rows, i want to assign triggers to A1, B1, C1 D1, E1 and more. therefore i wrote this that dynamically assign triggers to the cells.

```vb
    For j = 1 To 3  ' row
        For I = 1 To 4 ' columns
            If Target.Column = I And Target.Row = j Then
                If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                    Yes_4 = Yes_4 + 1
                    
                ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
                    No_4 = No_4 + 1
    
                ElseIf Target.Value = "Not applicable" Then
                    Not_Applicable_4 = Not_Applicable_4 + 1
    
                End If
                If Target.Value = "Green - Sufficient" Then
                    Green_4 = Green_4 + 1
                ElseIf Target.Value = "Orange - Largely sufficient with points for follow-up" Then
                    Orange_4 = Orange_4 + 1
                ElseIf Target.Value = "Red - Insufficient" Then
                    Red_4 = Red_4 + 1
                End If
     
                Range("O" & j).Value = "The ratings you selected are as follows:" + vbNewLine + "Yes: " & Str(Yes_4) + vbNewLine + "No: " & Str(No_4) + vbNewLine + "Green: " & Str(Green_4) _
                    + vbNewLine + "Orange: " & Str(Orange_4) + vbNewLine + "Red: " & Str(Red_4) + vbNewLine + "No Applicable: " & Str(Not_Applicable_4)
            End If
        Next I
    Next j
```

If the filled value of the cell is "Yes", the yes variable becomes yes + 1. not only for one cell, for every cell in the row, the summary is given in column O. for example: yes= 1, no =3, gree= 2 and so on.  it functions well. The problem is that when a "Yes" is selected in a cell, the value in column O shows that yes = 1, but if you change your mind and change it from "Yes" to "No", the value in column O shows that yes = 1, no =1. Instead of "No" = 1 and "Yes" = 0.

Comment: you have to have some kind of flag letting you know that it has already been calculated once and what the result of the previous calculation was.  getting this flag to persist once the above code goes out of scope is the real trick though

Comment: On which event is this code normally triggered? Also, did you declared the variables (Yes_4, No_4, etc.) outside of the Sub?

Comment: You need to reset your counters to zero after each row has been processed.  It would help a lot to show the rest of your code though.

Comment: @Slaqr yes i have declared the variables as global. that is why it keeps updating when there is an increase however no decrease.

Comment: @TimWilliams your idea seems to be help full can you may be explain it a bit more and if possible, a sample of code would help more. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign formulas to the result cells that reference the appropriate range, with the appropriate value, such as...

```
=countif(your range spec, "Yes")
=countif(your range spec, "Green")
```

If you need to adjust the range spec based on data conditions, you can update that formula in VBA reacting to the size of the range.  Otherwise you don't need vba to compute the totals.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a global variable to record the current value of the cell on SelectionChange, you can then check for changes and decrease the counter accordingly.

```
Dim sPrevious as string

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    sPrevious = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Then add into the existing Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  For j = 1 To 3  ' row
        For I = 1 To 4 ' columns
            If Target.Column = I And Target.Row = j Then

                If sPrevious <> Target.Value Then ''check if value has changed
                    If sPrevious = "Yes" Then
                        yes_4 = yes_4 - 1
                    ElseIf sPrevious = "No" Then
                        no_4 = no_4 - 1
                    ElseIf sPrevious = "Not applicable" Then
                        Not_Applicable_4 = Not_Applicable_4 - 1
                    End If
                    If sPrevious = "Green - Sufficient" Then
                        Green_4 = Green_4 - 1
                    ElseIf sPrevious = "Orange - Largely sufficient with points for follow-up" Then
                        Orange_4 = Orange_4 - 1
                    ElseIf sPrevious = "Red - Insufficient" Then
                        Red_4 = Red_4 - 1
                    End If
                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach using a dictionary to track the counts, and also to store the display values for the message:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngCheck As Range, rng As Range, rw As Range, c As Range, k, tmp
    Dim dict As Object, msg As String, v
    
    Set dict = GetTrackerDict()
   
    Set rngCheck = Me.Range("A2:D10")
    For Each rw In rngCheck.Rows
        'change in this row?
        If Not Application.Intersect(rw, Target) Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In rw.Cells
                v = c.Value
                If dict.exists(v) Then    'counting this value?
                    tmp = dict(v)         'get array from dict
                    tmp(1) = tmp(1) + 1   'increment count
                    dict(v) = tmp         'return array
                End If
            Next c
            'Build the message
            msg = "The ratings you selected are as follows:"
            For Each k In dict
                tmp = dict(k)
                msg = msg & vbNewLine & tmp(0) & ": " & tmp(1)
            Next k
            rw.EntireRow.Columns("O").Value = msg
            Set dict = GetTrackerDict() 'reset tracking
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

'Return a dictionary and with keys as the values to be counted
Function GetTrackerDict() As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    ' (add in the order to be displayed)
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.Add "Yes", Array("Yes", 0)  'array = (displayName, count)
    dict.Add "No", Array("No", 0)
    dict.Add "Green - Sufficient", Array("Green", 0)
    dict.Add "Orange - Largely sufficient with points for follow-up", Array("Orange", 0)
    dict.Add "Red - Insufficient", Array("Red", 0)
    dict.Add "Not applicable", Array("N/A", 0)
    Set GetTrackerDict = dict
End Function
```